# How to re declare value of array and initial value to html outside of each in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append data to html but using array variable outside of each function in jquery.

```
var prod_id, prod_name, prod_price;
var data_array = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('main/fcuk'); ?>",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, st) {
        $.each(data.data, function(i, obj) {
            obj = {
                prod_id: obj.prod_id,
                prod_name: obj.prod_name
            }
            data_array = obj;
        });
        console.log(data_array); // I will AppendTo an html element or selector here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the push method, As of now you are reassign the variable `data_array` with `obj` object.

```
$.each(data.data, function (i, obj) {
    obj = {prod_id: obj.prod_id, prod_name: obj.prod_name}
    data_array.push(obj);
});
console.log(data_array
```

OR, You can use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

> Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

```
data_array = $.map(data.data, function (obj) {
    return {prod_id: obj.prod_id, prod_name: obj.prod_name};
});
console.log(data_array)
```

Note: If you want to append it to HTML, Then create valid HTML and append the generate HTML or use various table/grid plugins.

Comment: When I used $.map I have to change the argument of a function inside of map like this function (obj, i).